# Ordering data set per group, sub-group and timestamp with small offset within groups

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns 1)timestamps, 2)groups 3)index inside the groups (sub-groups). A Group has 6 rows/indices and should always have the same timestamp with maximum allowed deviaiton of 2 seconds.
Sometimes some elements from two different groups have identical timestamps, but other elements don't. I need to be able to arrange the data according to timestamp to cluster the groups, but first considering that elements in the group might have an offset of max 2 seconds.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   timestamp1 = as.POSIXct(c(
      '2017-09-07 15:16:27',  '2017-09-07 15:16:27',  '2017-09-07 15:16:27',  '2017-09-07 15:16:27',  '2017-09-07 15:16:27',  '2017-09-07 15:16:27',
      '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', 
      '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', '2017-09-07 15:17:19', 
      '2017-09-07 15:17:20', '2017-09-07 15:17:20',
      '2017-09-07 15:17:20'
      )), 
   group = c(
      'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 
      'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
      'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa',
      'a', 'a',
      'aaa'
      ),
   index_inside_group = c(
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
      1, 3, 4, 6,
      1, 2, 4, 5, 6,
      2, 5,
      3
      )
   )
> df1
            timestamp1 group index_inside_group
1  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  1
2  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  2
3  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  3
4  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  4
5  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  5
6  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  6
7  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  1
8  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  3
9  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  4
10 2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  6
11 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  1
12 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  2
13 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  4
14 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  5
15 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  6
16 2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  2
17 2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  5
18 2017-09-07 15:17:20   aaa                  3
```

In short what I need is to get from data `df1` to `df2`

```
> df2
            timestamp1 group index_inside_group
1  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  1
2  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  2
3  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  3
4  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  4
5  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  5
6  2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  6
7  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  1
8  2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  2
9  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  3
10 2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  4
11 2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  5
12 2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  6
13 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  1
14 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  2
15 2017-09-07 15:17:20   aaa                  3
16 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  4
17 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  5
18 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  6
```

In `df2` the data is arranged with priority for `group`, then `index_inside_group` and only at the end `timestamp1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a long solution by looping through each unique timestamp, creating a new timestamp range with +/- 2 seconds and then grabbing all values that fall into that time range per group. 
In each iteration, the data chunks are ordered by `index_inside_group` and only then appended to re-create the `new_df` in the correct order.

```
new_df <- data.frame()
timestamps <- unique(df1$timestamp1)

for (i in 1:length(timestamps)){

   thisLL <- timestamps[i] - 2 # extend lower timestamp range by 2 seconds
   thisUL <- timestamps[i] + 2 # extend upper timestamp range by 2 seconds


   group_a <- df1[df1$timestamp1 >= thisLL & df1$timestamp1 <= thisUL & df1$group == 'a',] # search for timestamps in the ranges of first group
   group_a <- group_a[order(group_a$index_inside_group), ]  # ordering subset of first group

   group_aaa <- df1[df1$timestamp1 >= thisLL & df1$timestamp1 <= thisUL & df1$group == 'aaa',] # search for timestamps in the ranges of second group
   group_aaa <- group_aaa[order(group_aaa$index_inside_group), ] # ordering subset of second group


   new_df <- rbind(new_df, group_a, group_aaa)

}

new_df <- new_df[!duplicated(new_df[])] # having +/- 2 sec timestamp ranges for each unique timestamp means we can capture duplicates of 
                                        # the same data of one group, this removes last duplicates, just in case they happen

> new_df
             timestamp1 group index_inside_group
1   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  1
2   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  2
3   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  3
4   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  4
5   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  5
6   2017-09-07 15:16:27   aaa                  6
7   2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  1
16  2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  2
8   2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  3
9   2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  4
17  2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  5
10  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  6
11  2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  1
12  2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  2
18  2017-09-07 15:17:20   aaa                  3
13  2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  4
14  2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  5
15  2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  6
71  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  1
161 2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  2
81  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  3
91  2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  4
171 2017-09-07 15:17:20     a                  5
101 2017-09-07 15:17:19     a                  6
111 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  1
121 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  2
181 2017-09-07 15:17:20   aaa                  3
131 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  4
141 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  5
151 2017-09-07 15:17:19   aaa                  6
```